# How to address "Packages cannot be nested" error

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript, builder

I'm having a problem with Flex 4 beta 2...

I can't call a class using: `<fx:Script source:"myClass"/>`

For some reason, no matter what I do, the error is always the same:

> Packages cannot be nested

I found links to `help.adobe.com`, but they were all broken links.

So, is this a Flex bug or there is a new way to use external classes in Flash Builder 4?

Answer (score 1):

i think you have to write: <fx:Script source="myClass"/>
( no colon but the equal sign .... )

... and myClass must be an actionScript file and not a class

Comment: Actually, the Flash Builder intellisense tells me that I must use ":".

And about the class, it is a file with .as extension inside a proper package... I just dont know what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks NSP!

1. I removed the package and class declarations from my .as file (along with the scope brackets '{' and '}).
2. I used the '=' symbol as the assignment operator (as you suggested).

E.G.:

```
<fx:Script source="Greeter.as">
```

That did the trick.